# How can i know when a socket is idle?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, eofexception

I'm trying to write a client server application.
the clients post service requests and the server receives them and display them in a tech room.

everything was fine until I tried to send a screen capture to a special admin client, that should receive a screen capture of the list of live requests.

**my main server listening thread looks like this :**

```
while (true) {

         clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
         log.debug("Server Started Listening");
         is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
         os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

 // An option for a stop listening button. currently not available !
         if( listening==true )  {
         line = is.readUTF();
         os.println(line); 
         System.out.println(line);
         RequestReciever.pharseToRequest(line);
}
```

**The pharseToRequest Method looks like this :**

```
public static void pharseToRequest(String input) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(";;;")));
    if (list.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Login") && list.get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("Login") && list.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
    {
        _adminClients.add(list.get(4));
        updateScreenCapture();
        AdminClientUpdate tmp = new AdminClientUpdate(list.get(4));
        Thread aCU = new Thread (tmp);
        aCU.start();
    }
    else
    {
    ServerRequest newReq = new ServerRequest(list.get(0), list.get(1), Integer.parseInt(list.get(2)),list.get(3),list.get(4));
    addRequest(newReq);
    }
}
```

when the client sends "Login" as the data, I treat him as an ADMIN CLIENT, and try to send it a screencapture, via the AdminclientUpdate thread.

and when a client sent regular data, I just update it on the server screen with the "addRequest" method.

the problem I have is when I try to send the screen capture, it will find its way to the admin client and will be updated there correctly, but my server gets an error and stops working.

I suspect it might have something to do with the listening thread still have data in it from the old request while the AdminclientUpdate thread transferring data, or something.

**This is the Error I get from the server , after sending the screen capture :**

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at ListeningThread.run(ListeningThread.java:50)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The serversocket.accept() continutes reading as is just received a new request from a client ,
when it really did not...
instead of pausing and waiting for a new request...

I'm stuck with this for two weeks now, and very frustrated.

please HELP.

David.

Comment: Your server should start a new thread to handle every accepted connection, instead of processing each one in-line in the accept thread.

Comment: I have managed to fix some of the problem by doing so. everything works fine on the first client login.  now i'm looking for a way to initialize updates **from the server**, when there is a change, to the client. do I have to add a serversocket on the client too in order to do so ? or is there any other , more elegant wayu to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case The server should start a new thread to handle every accepted connection, instead of processing each one in-line in the accept thread.
But also I tried to get the first update via the serversocket instead of the login initialization.
now, after getting the 1st update while logging in, I added a Server Socket on the client side so it will keep listening for further updates from server.

EJP's idea gave me the first lead.